# Why are old questions on top?

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign, questions, recent-activity

There are many old questions showing on the start page of superuser.com. If I open one of them, I see old dates both in answers, comments, and the editing time of the question.

How/why are these get to the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What can cause a question to be bumped?

> What can cause a question to be "bumped" to the first page in the Active tab of a Stack Exchange site? (Changing the "Last Active" date.)

...

> The following activities will cause a question to be bumped:
>
> - Addition of an answer
> - Editing the question or any of its answers (even if the answer is deleted) * † ‡
>
>   - A suggested edit gets approved
> - Editing duplicates list of the question
> - Starting a new bounty (not awarding of an existing bounty, see below)
> - Successful reopening (if the question was closed previously)
> - The Community user will bump non-negatively scored, open questions every hour that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none
>     scoring more than that.
>
>   - Questions are picked randomly from the top-viewed questions with new activity more than 30 days ago.
>   - The maximum number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the site: 4 per hour on Stack Overflow, 2 per hour on Super
>       User and Server Fault, and 1 per hour on Meta Stack Exchange and all
>       other sites.

Source [What can cause a question to be bumped? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)

Comment: Thanks. The word "bumped" was unknown to me.